# Issues with cardinality

Tags: set-theory

1. How many distinct possible axioms are expressible in a first-order language? My hypothesis is aleph null, countably infinite.
2. How many possible (finite) combinations of such axioms are there? My guess is aleph one, the cardinality of the continuum; because this would be equivalent to taking the power set of (1).
3. For a collection of axioms, let’s consider an algorithm that enumerates the entire theory of those axioms (all the true formulae). Does that algorithm have a general form? For each axiom, the question becomes if it can have some other axiom applied to it, to derive a new, valid formula. Not all combinations are valid. I wonder if an analog of the formula for the Von Neumann universe could be considered an upper bound? For set of axioms {a, b, c, …}, we generate a hypothetical “next generation” of theorems with the Von Neumann formula, {(a -> b), (a -> c), …}. Some issues with this is that if a formula has multiple variables, there would be a combinatorial term for how many ways you could apply axiom a to b. Most of the resulting attempted “applications” would be invalid. My guess is, the size of a theory generated by a set of axioms is bounded by the power set of the cardinality of the set of axioms. (Or maybe it depends strongly on how many variable terms are provided, in the language.)
4. There does not appear to be a “biggest set”, due to Russell’s paradox. However, people have tried to be able to talk about “a collection of all sets” by inventing a second concept, for example, a “proper class”. This seems conceptually unjustified, but Grothendieck abstracted it with his universe axioms, which are simple. A universe is a transitive set which contains all power sets and all images of functions. The key universe axiom says that any set is contained by a universe. But does this solve the problem? The whole reason people invented “classes” was *so* they could talk about “the totality of sets”. A chain of containing universes would immediately imply, “what do you call the totality of universes”? Shouldn’t we just accept uncontained infinity as unavoidable?
5. I don’t fully understand the nature of uncountability. The awesome thing about countably infinite sets is that they can be enumerated - you could calculate the details of every element (if you had the time). This would motivate us to enumerate every possible collection of first-order axioms and its ensuing theory, and then over that enumerate all possible “properties” of a theory (soundness, completeness, etc.), to find out which collections of axioms have which properties. When something is not countable, you can no longer enumerate it. I find this weird, because the rational numbers are bijective with and of the same cardinality as the natural numbers, but you cannot “enumerate” all the rational numbers between 2 and 3. (Or, can you?)
6. Is this why we need the axiom of replacement? I haven’t yet grasped what it does. Does it allow us to define bijections like that of the natural numbers onto the rationals, then claim such sets exist?

Related: [indefinite extensibility](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-56/issue-1/Varieties-of-Indefinite-Extensibility/10.1215/00294527-2835056.pdf).

Comment: You need to ask these questions one at a time on Math SE. The set of finite subsets of a countable set is countable, so you still get aleph null in 2. Aleph one is not the cardinality of the continuum without the (unprovable) continuum hypothesis. One can enumerate all rational numbers between 2 and 3 easily, there is a rational bijection between the real line and (2,3), etc.

Comment: Replacement is saying that if you have a set *A* and a formula *φ(x,y)* such that all for every  *x* in *A*, they’re is a specific *y* such that *φ(x,y)*, then there is another set  *B* that contains exactly those *y* such that *φ(x,y)* holds with respect to *A*. For example, you can define other infinite sets using replacement and the Axiom of Infinity.

Comment: For 1, merely consider an uncountable signature, say that of a typical vector space. Now modify 2,3

Comment: 4. G.  introduced universes for their utility, not to resolve some russellian paradox. 5. I think you need to refresh your set theory 6. replacement is mostly unncessary for day to day math, including this

Comment: Uncountability means that you cannot be enumerated using natural numbers. You could still "enumerate" an uncountable set A  by any set which you can inject A into. I.E. construct an injection f, from A into it.

Comment: That there is no largest set, is not from the Russel Paradox, but from a related Result from Cantor- that there is no surjection from a set to its Powerset. So, For any set X, the Powerset of X  has greater  cardinality than X.

Answer (score 2):

> 6. Is this why we need the axiom of replacement? I haven’t yet grasped what it does. [...]

It says 'the universe is closed under definable functions', in that it guarantees that for a (first-order) formula (in the language of set theory) that 'could be' a function with a set A as domain, the range actually exists and is also a set B

The 'simplest' example is probably allowing us to prove the second limit ordinal ω+ω actually exists, by using the formula

φ := "y = ω+x"

on ω, so that one obtains its range

B = {ω, ω+1, ω+2, ..., ω+n, ...}

and then

ω + ω := ω ∪ B

> [...] Does it allow us to define bijections like that of the natural numbers onto the rationals, then claim such sets exist?

It's neither necessairy nor seemingly useful for this

> 5. I don’t fully understand the nature of uncountability. The awesome thing about countably infinite sets is that they can be enumerated - you could calculate the details of every element (if you had the time). [...]

'calculate the details of every element' doesn't make any sense, as does the rest of the paragraph, except for

> [...] because the rational numbers are bijective with and of the same cardinality as the natural numbers, but you cannot “enumerate” all the rational numbers between 2 and 3. (Or, can you?)

which is simply wrong: a bijection with the naturals is exactly what an 'enumeration' is

> 4. There does not appear to be a “biggest set”, due to Russell’s paradox. [...]

Cantor's theorem on the size of power sets is (usually) enough to rule out a biggest set

> However, people have tried to be able to talk about “a collection of all sets” by inventing a second concept, for example, a “proper class”. This seems conceptually unjustified, [...]

There's nothing wrong with class theories having proper classes

> [...] The key universe axiom says that any set is contained by a universe.

[MacLane may not agree](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/bfb0059147)

> Shouldn’t we just accept uncontained infinity as unavoidable?

In a certain sense, Replacement does that: no single set is cofinal, much less exhausts, 'the universe of all sets'

> 3. For a collection of axioms, let’s consider an algorithm that enumerates the entire theory of those axioms (all the true formulae). Does that algorithm have a general form?

Do such algorithms always exist?

> 1. How many distinct possible axioms are expressible in a first-order language? My hypothesis is aleph null, countably infinite.

Any formula can be taken to be an axiom, and there are languages with uncountably many symbols

> How many possible (finite) combinations of such axioms are there?

[Depends a bit on the size of the language one starts with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)

> My guess is aleph one, the cardinality of the continuum; because this would be equivalent to taking the power set of (1).

Not correct, check the previous link

Answer (score 1):

I'll respond to (4) at length, because the gaps/errors in the presentation are perhaps more subtle than with respect to the other questions.

Firstly:

> There does not appear to be a “biggest set”, due to Russell’s paradox.

To be technically exact, the problem is not just with the concept of a universal set by itself but in connection with the axiom of separation. Having separation apply to a universal set "downwardly" is roughly equivalent to having unrestricted comprehension "upwardly." But so then the axiom of separation, as an axiom, is not supposed to be a logically necessary principle of logic, but a substantive thesis. Then for theories with different kinds or ranges of comprehension/separation principles, retaining a universal set is a live option (pursued in the case of e.g. Quine's New Foundations or Esser's positive set theory). Paraconsistent set theorists bite all the bullets, of course, retaining a universal set in the face of various contradictions.

You continue:

> However, people have tried to be able to talk about “a collection of all sets” by inventing a second concept, for example, a “proper class”. This seems conceptually unjustified ... The whole reason people invented “classes” was so they could talk about “the totality of sets”. A chain of containing universes would immediately imply, “what do you call the totality of universes”? Shouldn’t we just accept uncontained infinity as unavoidable?

The typical technical definition of a proper class **is of uncontained infinity**: to be precise, a proper class enters into the ∈ relation from the "has as an element" direction but never the "is an element of" direction. By the [axiom of limitation of size](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size#:%7E:text=The%20axiom%20of%20limitation%20of%20size%20says%20that%20a%20class,that%20maps%20it%20onto%20V.), they are then of "the largest infinite size" (absolute infinity) and are uncontained by any set. QED, indeed!

On the other hand, in category theory for example, there is this desire to talk about the totality of all classes. The best the baseline theory can do is talk about a class of which all other classes are *sub*classes, and Hamkins (among others) has developed a [mereological interpretation of this relationship](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06593.pdf), where the subclasses are parts of the universal total. However, the natural progression (in category theory) is to start going on about "a [conglomerate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conglomerate_(mathematics)) of all classes," which ends up meaning that we have another ∈-like relation between classes and conglomerates, etc.

**Addendum: "in praise of replacement"**

(The title of the addendum is a covert joke, since there is an [essay](https://math.bu.edu/people/aki/20.pdf) by a prominent set theorist (Kanamori) that has the same title.)  Originally, the motivation for replacement was to be able to get ℵ<sub>ω</sub> as a set instead of as the equivalent of the universe. In other words, in ZFC minus replacement, |*V*| = ℵ<sub>ω</sub> (or then ORD = ω<sub>ω</sub>). This is unseemly, since then the universe would have countable cofinality, but we normally expect *V* (or ORD) to be self-cofinal.

Secondly, then, the axiom of limitation of size implies the axiom of replacement. So if one accepts the one (on grounds of proper class theory/the theory of absolute infinity), one should be minded to accept the other. (I don't think the thesis is provable in the reverse direction, though, i.e. I don't think that replacement directly implies limitation of size, but I don't remember the details clearly right now.)

Comment: Would you be willing to respond to the other questions as well? Thanks.

Comment: I can tie in some stuff about replacement to the response to (4), so I'll do that.

Comment: Thanks. “*the problem is not just with the concept of a universal set by itself but in connection with the axiom of separation.*” Are you saying “the axiom of infinity does not give us problems until combined with the axiom of separation”? What would happen if we just got rid of the axiom of separation? Has anybody tried this?

Comment: Anyway. Some really good stuff to follow up on here. Thanks!

Comment: @JuliusHamilton When you get rid of Separation (aka Specification), that's when you get Russell's paradox. It's Separation that fixes the problem, by requiring an already existing container set. That is, {x : x ∉ x} leads to contradiction; and {x ∈ X: x ∉ x} does not, where X is some set that we already know exists. It's Specification that requires the containing set X. The axiom of infinity is not involved here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification

Comment: @JuliusHamilton if you have a universal set, then assuming the separation axiom, you can separate Russell's set from it (the other route is to summon Russell's set out of the ether using naive comprehension). An axiom of a universal set might be glossed as a (very strong) axiom of infinity, but it would be far beyond the axiom of mere omega with which ZFC concerns itself. As for getting rid of separation, well, from the experimental multiverse standpoint of the set theory community today, I imagine they've toyed with separation-minus theories, or at least truncated separation, but...

Comment: ... if one imagines that "being in a set" is like "being conceptually attended to," then our ability to take, say, {A, B, C} and focus on just A and B to get another set {A, B}, makes separation look very generalizable/far-reaching, so truncating separation at some infinite cardinal height, or eliminating it altogether, is not "intuitively" very appealing/plausible. Luckily, of course, intuition is not too much trusted as a ground in higher set theory, so we also would wonder about "extrinsic evidence" (does limiting/denying separation have any "useful" results?).